# How can I merge/integrate multiple independent web applications?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, spring-boot, vue.js

I have developed three different web apps. Let me say app A is written in Springboot and Angular, app B is written in Node and React, and app C is written in Node and Vue. They are all role-based applications, and each one has its own authentication service. They are in use currently, but the application owners want me to integrate apps B and C into app A so that once they log into app A, they can access the other applications (similar to how you can access confluence, Trello, etc from Jira) or photos, contacts, maps, etc when logged into Gmail.
Any ideas on how I should go about it? I have decided to implement SSO, but how do I go about with the frontend? I thought of providing nav links to the other apps but to what routes? Secondly, I don't want to open the other apps in a different tab.

Comment: You can use a reverse proxy like `nginx` to forward the requests to the corresponding app, and have them in the same domain but different paths. `example.com/appA`, `example.com/appB`, and `example.com/appC`. And maybe create an appN to handle authentication.

Comment: BTW, this is an interesting question but opinionated, so it might get deleted https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: At front end they are supposed to communicate through browser storage and url params (probably hash part) if app instances don't work at the same time. And through window events and globals and possible a mediator app if they work simultaneously.

Comment: @EstusFlask, your point is not very clear. Can you please come clearer?

Comment: A colleague dev suggested what you are suggesting @eventHandler, but I'm yet to give it a try. I will give it a try and give feedback.

Comment: The question is not very clear, I'm not sure in which way I could explain better. This totally depend on how the apps are supposed to interact. The question may be too broad for SO regardless, consider reasking at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if it's closed